# Dynamical system $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n - \frac{1}{x_n}) \ \ , \ \ n = 0, 1 , 2,...$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

> Consider the dynamical system
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n - \frac{1}{x_n}) \ \ , \ \ n = 0, 1 , 2,...
> $$

So by using the substitution $x_n = \cot(y_n)$, I have found:
$$
x_n = \cot(\cot^{-1} (x_0) \cdot 2^n )
$$

but the next part of the question says

> Let us parametrize the initial condition $x_0$ by means of a unique angle $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ such that $x_0 = \cot(\theta)$. Show that, for every $p>1$, the choice
>   $$
> \theta = \theta_p := \frac{\pi}{2^p - 1}
> $$
>   yields a period-p solution.

So I know I have to show that $x_n = x_{n+p}$, that is:
$$
cot(\frac{\pi}{2^p - 1} \cdot 2^n) = cot(\frac{\pi}{2^p - 1} \cdot 2^{n+p})
$$
and so, using periodicity of $\cot$, that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2^p - 1} \cdot 2^n + k \pi= \frac{\pi}{2^p - 1} \cdot 2^{n+p}
$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Inductively, we have for $p = 1$ that $\theta_1 = \pi$ hence
$$
x_{n+1} = \cot (\pi \cdot 2^{n+1}) = \cot(\pi \cdot 2^n + \pi \cdot 2^n) = \cot(\pi \cdot 2^n) = x_n
$$
and so we have a period-1 solution. How do I show the inductive step for this proof?

Comment: Note that this dynamical system corresponds to Newton's method for $f(z)=z^2+1$. The global basins of attractions are the upper and lower open half planes. The real line is the Julia set and the dynamics is chaotic there. Hence the expectation that periodic points of all periods will appear.

Answer (score 1):

For $x_0=\cot(\theta)$ we have that

$x_1=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}-\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\Big]= \cot(2\theta)$

and inductively

$x_{n}=\cot(2^n\theta)$

Thus when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2^p-1}$ we obtain

$x_{n+p}=\cot\big(\frac{2^{n+p}\pi}{2^p-1}\big)=\cot\Big(\frac{2^n(2^{p}-1)\pi}{2^p-1}+\frac{2^{n}\pi}{2^p-1}\Big)=\cot\Big(2^n\pi+\frac{2^{n}\pi}{2^p-1}\Big)=\cot\Big(\frac{2^{n}\pi}{2^p-1}\Big)=x_n$

since $2^n\pi$ ia an integer multiple of $\pi$.